# Setting value to field on 2nd form from 1st form linked button press in SAP B1

Tags: c#, sapb1

I have the following code to click on a linked button on one form matrix and open another form.

However, I want to open a specific document on the 2nd form based on a value in the column and row a user is clicking on.

I have this so far:

```
Application.SBO_Application.ActivateMenuItem("FreightForwarders.FileMaster");
Application.SBO_Application.Forms.ActiveForm.Mode = SAPbouiCOM.BoFormMode.fm_FIND_MODE;                    
Application.SBO_Application.Forms.ActiveForm.Items.Item("Item_31").Enabled = true;
Application.SBO_Application.Forms.ActiveForm.ActiveItem = "Item_31";
Application.SBO_Application.Forms.ActiveForm.Items.Item("Item_31").Specific.Value = prj;
Application.SBO_Application.Forms.ActiveForm.Items.Item("1").Click(SAPbouiCOM.BoCellClickType.ct_Regular);
Application.SBO_Application.Forms.ActiveForm.Items.Item("Item_31").Enabled = false;
Application.SBO_Application.Forms.ActiveForm.Mode = SAPbouiCOM.BoFormMode.fm_OK_MODE;
```

How do I set the value prj? Specific.Value does not work.

Using SAP B1 Version 10 PL 2202

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is "item_31" an EditText ?

as far as i can see the code should work but you could try declaring the item and assigning the value:

```
SAPbouiCOM.EditText myItem31 = Application.SBO_Application.Forms.ActiveForm.Items.Item("Item_31");
        myItem31.Value = "Pjr";
```

You could also try using String instead of Value:

```
Application.SBO_Application.Forms.ActiveForm.Items.Item("Item_31").Specific.String = prj;
```